# Linking from SharePoint Office 365 to OneNote Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onenote

In OneNote desktop, you can right-click a page, and copy a link to the clipboard.  You can then paste that link into other apps like Excel or Word.

In SharePoint Office 365, you can create a custom list with a hyperlink, but you cannot paste that copied OneNote link into the SharePoint column without getting an "invalid URL" OR the "URL longer than 255 characters" message.

Has anyone solved what ideally would be a very easy thing to connect two Microsoft products?

[image: OneNote Get Link to Page]

[image: Invalid URL Message]

[image: URL May not contain more than 255 characters]

Answer (score 2):

**Invalid URL error**

The http:// and https:// protocols are supported in the Link column in SharePoint Online. “onenote:///” is not supported.

**URL may not contain more than 255 characters**

SharePoint limits URL length. The max number of characters in hyperlink column is 255. We cannot enter the URL that's longer than 255 characters.

**Workaround:**

You can upload your OneNote to a SharePoint Online library or OneDrive for Business, then use that file path.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Joanna's answer:
If your OneNote notebook is stored in a SharePoint 365 library, then you can obtain a web link from the web-based version of the OneNote notebook, and

Answer (score 0):

Joanna's answer brings you halfway there:

The link might still be to long. In my case, the "Copy Link to this Page" provides something like

`https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc={<guid>}&action=edit&<some very long redundant Address...>`

which is still far too long.

After cutting off everything after {}, the link ist short enough and still works.

THE SIMPLER WAY:

After storing the OneNote Page in OneNote Online:

1. Open the Page in OneNote Online
2. Clik on the Share Button in the Upper left corner

   [image: Share Page (Germa)]
3. Copy the Link

   [image]
4. Paste the link into the SharePoint Link-Field

This matches like`https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/:o:/g/<46 characters>?e=<6 characters>`, about 100 characters, dependant of the legngt of the tenant name.